# Google Drive API Authentication - how to do it and how to implement it?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the title of a document using the file ID. Here's the code:

```
private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {

  try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  }
}
}
```

However, when I run it I receive a 403 forbidden error that states, "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

I assume that I have to authenticate, but seeing as I'm completely new to Google Drive API and also java, I'm confused as to how to do this (forgive me). I found this webpage: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server which explains how to authenticate but I'm still confused. The page lists multiple classes that do thing such as exchange the authorization code for an access token and use OAuth 2.0 credentials.

My question is do I need to use all of these classes to authenticate? And how do I implement them into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief explanation at the http level.

- Any Google Drive REST API call requires an http `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx` to be set. If there is no such header, you'll get the 403 you're experiencing
- The xxxxx is an access token. There are a myriad ways to get one of these depending on the user experience you want to implement and whether you're trying to access the user's Drive files or the application's. Read the Google docs and experiment with the OAuth Playground.

The Google Java library attempts to abstract all of the above. Whether it does a good job or not is for you to decide. Personally I've had more success calling the REST API directly.

Comment: How do you call it directly?

Comment: As per https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get, your call would be GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId